# Showing that intersection is not empty in probability space

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Given a probability measure space $(X,A ,\mu)$ where we have a finite sequence of sets $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}\text{...},A_{n}$ that belong to $A$ such that $\sum^{n}_{k=1}\mu (A_{k})>n-1$,
I would like to show $$\mu \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A^{c}_{k} \right)<1$$

I don't have a lot of ideas on how to solve this. It seems intuitively clear to me that for the $A_{k}$ sets to have a sum larger than $n-1$ they have to "share" some elements, ie. their intersection can not be empty. If we could show this, the problem would be solved. Any ideas or hints are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mu \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k^c \right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(A_k^c) = \sum_{k=1}^n (1-\mu(A_k)) = n- \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(A_k) < 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \sum_k 1_{A_k}(x)$. Note that $f(x)=n $ **iff** $x \in \cap_k A_k = \cup_k A_k^c$. You want to show that $\mu A >0$, where $A=\{ x | f(x) = n \} $.

We are given $\int f > n-1$.

Suppose $\mu A =0$. Then $f(x) \le n-1$ ae. and so $\int f \le n-1$, a contradiction.